# Unable to connect to Postgre SQL data base

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have just installed Postgre SQL on Windows 10. I can connect to the data base via PSQL and pgAdmin fine.

The problem is that I can neither connect to the data base using C# or an .udl-test file.

[image]

My C# code:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(
  "Data Source=localhost;" +
  "User id=postgres;" +
  "Password=postgres;" +
  "connection timeout=10");

connection.Open();
```

This gives me an exception (server not found).

Answer (score 1):

SqlConnection is for SQL Server only. You could use NpgsqlConnection from Npgsql  library. Simple example from library developers:

```
var connString = "Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase";

using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Insert some data
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES (@p)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", "Hello world");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // Retrieve all rows
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT some_field FROM data", conn))
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html